# SMACK labels for created files not set

Tags: linux, security, filesystems, attr

I’m trying to setup SMACK on my system but am having some strange problems.

I have SMACK turned on in my kernel and have added the line:

```
 smackfs /smack smackfs smackfsdef=* 0 0
```

to my `/etc/fstab` file.  SMACK seems to be enforcing labelled subject/object access as expected. But when I create new files the files do not have the labels of the creating process. Instead the labels are blank.

My kernel version is 3.4.36. My kernel config includes:

```
CONFIG_NETLABEL=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_NETWORK=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SMACK=y
CONFIG_DEFAULT_SECURITY_SMACK=y
CONFIG_DEFAULT_SECURITY="smack"
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Linux kernel configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer to my own question.  The yaffs2 file system that my device runs on does not fully support extended attributes for newly created files.